# Specify response type for springdoc/io.swagger.core.v3 "ApiResponse"

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I have an @RestController endpoint defined as

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/end/point/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> endpoint(
            @PathVariable("id") @NotBlank @Pattern(regexp ="^[A-Za-z]$") String cdsId){
...
conditions to return boolean
...
    }
```

I want the OpenApi3 documentation for this to look something like the following. Specifically, I do *not* want a "content" section, but instead want to be able to define the response *type* as such:

```
"200": {
    "description": "OK",
    "type": "boolean"
}
```

However, using springdoc/io.swagger.core.v3 ApiResponses/ApiResponse like the following:

```
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK" )})
```

produces

```
"200": {
   "description":"OK",
    "content": {
        "*/*": {
            "schema": {
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do *not* want the "content" section at all, as the security scan says that we are running labels it incorrect. At the same time, I want to do this programatically so that I don't have to manually change it every time I retrieve the Api Docs from my app. ApiResponse type does not provide a "type" field and automatically generates "content". Can I handle this in the ApiResponse class?

Answer (score 1):

#### What is OpenAPI's Response Object?

As outlined in the OpenAPI specification, the [response object](https://swagger.io/specification/#response-object) can have the below properties

- `description` - Some description about the response that's returned.
- `headers` - Specifies any additional headers that returned as part of the response. An example is the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header, which can be optionally set as per the requirement. Note that `Content-Type` isn't a response header but is considered as entity-headers as defined in [RFC-7231, section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3).
- `content` - The actual response object (a plain string is also an object) returned as part of the response.
- `links` - A map of operational links. An example would be, the links to next/previous/first/last pages when paging is implemented in a search operation.

#### A closer look at the `content` property

The property takes in a Map of `String` (denoting the response code) and [MediaType](https://swagger.io/specification/#media-type-object) object (denoting the response body).

```yaml
200:
  description: successful operation
  content:
    application/xml:
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
    application/json:
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
400:
  description: Bad Request
  content: {}
```

In the above example `200` and `400` represent the response codes. When we look into the `content` for the `200` response, it tells that the response can either be in XML or JSON format as specified in the `Content-Type` header of the request. For the `400`, an empty content (`{}`) means that no response-body will be returned.

Under each content-type, the `schema` describes the object that'll be returned for the given response code. For the `200` response it tells that an array will be returned that'll consist of items of the type `Pet`.

Now, to answer your question.

You can **NOT** define the response as you said in the below example

```json
"200": {
    "description": "OK",
    "type": "boolean"
}
```

This is strictly against the specification and when you try this in the [swagger-editor](https://editor.swagger.io/), it'll indicate an error due to invalid schema.

The error that's shown in the spec editor is shown below.

[image]

The error in the Swagger-UI is shown below

[image]